# Nginx location ~ /\.ht

Tags: nginx

What is the meaning of the following `location` block in Nginx?

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

I ask since I have a small WordPress site and I removed this block from its configuration and restarted the server but the site kept working fine, seemingly.

Comment: Keeps people from downloading your security-related files. Only the web server needs to read them, not the general public.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

This directive tells the webserver to deny all incoming requests for any files starting with `.ht` in the root directory (`/`).

The tilde `~` tells nginx to use regular expressions.

Thus, files like `.htaccess`, `.htpasswd`, etc, will not be served.

Note: The backslash (`\`) before the dot, is just to escape the dot (the dot that comes before `htaccess`, `htpassword`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Say your website is example.com. The particular location will be `example.com/.ht`. So the `deny all` directive will deny all requests to `example.com/.ht*`. (* indicate any following string)

`~` say `nginx` to go for regular expression based matching. `/` is root directory of your website. `\` is escape character. It says to interpret `.` literally and not as a part of regular expression.